Serde doesn't see untagged enum variant in input ("data did not match any variant of untagged ...")
Using Serde, I want to parse JSON data like this:
{
  "data_type": "uint8",
  "scales": [{
    "encoding": "jpeg",
    "key": "4.0x4.0x33.0"
  }]
}

It should be read into the following types:
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct DatasetAttributes {
    data_type: String,
    scales: Vec<ScaleEntry>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct ScaleEntry {
    pub encoding: CompressionType,
    pub key: String,
}

#[derive(Clone, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
#[serde(rename_all = "lowercase")]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum CompressionType {
    Raw(RawCompression),
    Jpeg(JpegCompression),
}

#[derive(Clone, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
#[serde(rename_all = "lowercase")]
pub struct JpegCompression {
    quality: i32,
}

#[derive(Clone, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug, Default)]
pub struct RawCompression;


With the above JSON I do however get the following error:
Error: data did not match any variant of untagged enum CompressionType

Am I misunderstanding how Serde looks for untagged data or what is wrong with the above?

Doesn't look like a duplicate to me; this looks to be about deserialization while the other is just about serialization

@kmdreko I didn't even realize the other Q/A wasn't about deserialization when I applied & tested it, but the solution to add #[serde(skip)] does work for it
